# Using java variable in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Is there any way to use a java variable in my build.gradle version field so I don't need to manually change the build script everytime I make a new build?

So something like this

```
group = 'project_name'
version = <insert variable from java file>
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
```

Comment: How'd the value of this variable change? In other words, how do you increment the version?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I want to increment the project build version in a java variable defined in my project

Comment: That makes no sense. You can define the variable in `buildSrc`, but your build won't be modifying it. Besides, builds can run on your PC, CI server, another dude's Mac, how'd all these versions remain in sync?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar how does that not make sense?


Why can't I use a java version in the build script? Is it not possible to do something like this?


In java class: `String myVersion: "1.0"`


In build.gradle:  `version = myVersion`

Comment: I already said, you can define the variable in `buildSrc`. What doesn't make sense is that you want to have a variable that you don't know how to increment.

Comment: @JonathanLai I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're after. Perhaps if you describe your build process and clarify what exactly you're attempting to implement then someone can offer a proper solution.

Comment: @Slaw I just want to be able to change my program's version without having to edit multiple files. I figured that the best way would be to change a variable in my java class everytime I make a release but I would also like those changed to be reflected in my build.gradle version field. That way, the version can be seen in my code as well instead of just the properties file

Comment: @JonathanLu That's backwards. You should have Gradle manage the version of your project.

Comment: @Slaw Yea I had a hunch I was doing things backwards. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Java source file to manage the version of your project is backwards. You should let your build system—in this case, Gradle—manage the version. When you update the version in Gradle you should have setup the build in such a way that the new version is propagated throughout the project.

Within the build script this is easily accomplished; you simply have to reference the `version` property everywhere you need it. The concept isn't any different than passing data around in your application. Remember that, in Gradle, the build script is written in Groovy or Kotlin and normal programming logic applies (the build script is essentially an object which implements both `org.gradle.api.Project` and `org.gradle.api.Script`).

The more difficult part is making sure your application can see the version without having to update the version in both the build script and the source code. There are, however, a number of ways to accomplish this, such as:

1. Create a properties file as a resource and use the `processResources` Gradle task to inject the project's version into said properties file. Then read the resource at runtime to get the application version.
2. Create a custom Gradle task which generates a properties file as a resource. Then read the resource at runtime to get the application version.
3. Create a custom Gradle task which generates the Java source file (e.g. `AppVersion.java`) that represents your application's version.
4. Use the `jar` Gradle task to set the `Implementation-Version` attribute of the manifest. Then read this attribute at runtime to get the application's version.
5. If using Java 9+ and modules then you can have the `compileJava` Gradle task set the module version. Then you can read the module version at runtime.

You might also want to consider keeping the version in the `gradle.properties` file and reading it from there into your build script (Gradle provides an API for this). That way when you update the version the build script doesn't have to be recompiled (at least that's the case with the Kotlin DSL).

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely look into that